# Plupload в nodejs distination filenames in OS

Tags: node.js

Друзья! Есть node js, есть plupload. Файлы загружаются. После загрузки файлов, сами файлы принимают вид sY9YhUr-QvlU_XzLKHeT5kP1.jpg. unique_names пробовал и false и true, всё равно такие имена файлов, да и Бог с ними, как их названия вытащить? Мне их дальше в mongo хранить.

```
    //Сам uploader
            var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                browse_button: 'browse', 
                url: '/upload',
                runtimes : 'html5,html4',
                max_file_size : '30mb',
                filters : [
                    {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
                    {title : "Video files", extensions : "avi,wmv,mp4"}

                ],
                unique_names: true,
                views: {
                    list: true,
                    thumbs: true, 
                    active: 'thumbs'
                },
                flash_swf_url : '/js/Moxie.swf',
                silverlight_xap_url : '/js/Moxie.xap',
                init: {
                    UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                        // console.log('test');
                        var a = $('#editable-select').val();
                        var b = a.split(" ");
                        var target_id = b[b.length - 1];
                        // console.log(target_id);
                        files[files.length] = target_id;

                        socket.emit('files', files);
                    }
                }
            });

     uploader.init();

        uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
            console.log(up,files);
            var html = '';
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                html += '<li id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></li>';
            });
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += html;
            uploader.start();
        });

        uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        });

        uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
        });
//Обработчик 
pluploader.on('error', function(error) {
        throw error;
    });
    app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
        pluploader.handleRequest(req, res);
        // console.log(res);
    });
    pluploader.on('fileUploaded', function(file, req) {
        console.log(file);

   // доступ к именам файлов для создания ссылок в монго - file.name

    });


//html
<ul id="filelist"></ul>
<div id="console"></div>

//Вывод из консоли, мол файл загружен и его target_name, которым и должен называться файл (Правильно?) Но файл называется:sY9YhUr-QvlU_XzLKHeT5kP1.jpg
{ name: 'o_1c8u9d8ncn461v7b1biud7dg52d.jpg',
  data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 ff e1 10 36 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 07 01 32 00 02 00 00 00 14 00 00 ... >,
  size: 595284,
  type: 'image/jpeg' }
{ id: 'o_1c8u9d8ncn461v7b1biud7dg52d',
  name: 'Hydrangeas.jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  size: 595284,
  origSize: 595284,
  loaded: 595284,
  percent: 100,
  status: 5,
  lastModifiedDate: '2009-07-14T05:32:31.658Z',
  completeTimestamp: 1521434927898,
  target_name: 'o_1c8u9d8ncn461v7b1biud7dg52d.jpg' }
```

Я пробовал в php обработать uploader'ом который все рекомендуют - всё работает и имена файлов такие как target_name. Посмотрел код php uploader-а, из него ясно, что он принимает значение REQUEST['name'] из глобального массива. Хорошо, тогда я поставил себе в nodejs request и попробовал посмотреть все переменные которые "ходят" через request. Имя файла обнаружено не было. Прошу помощи, друзья.

Answer (score 1):

Если кому-то поможет, я нашел решение. Нужно добавить в обработчик fileUploaded функцию записи файла в каталог. А те "странные имена", видимо, временные файлы поправьте меня, знатоки. В общем, вот код:

```
pluploader.on('fileUploaded', function(file, req) {
        var target_path = "./upload/"+file.name;
        fs.writeFile(target_path, file.data,function(err){
            console.log(file);
        }) ;
```

Comment: Вы писали, что файл сохраняется. Где вообще были те файлы со странными именами?